Why would my value be wrong at the 4th decimal when I use MPI to message pass it between 2 nodes?
I am using MPI to message pass data values, some of them with a lot of decimal places, and I need them all to be accurate to around 6-8 decimal places. I have several implementations of my program (python, c++ with openmp, cuda) that I have run on several different systems and architectures, so I already know what the data values should be and that it is possible to achieve these exact values with different libraries on different architectures.
When using MPI on a single node of my cluster system, I get the exact values; however, when I use 2 nodes I get the errors starting with the 4th decimal place (so it's only accurate for the first 3 decimal places). All nodes are the same architecture and were bought and installed at the same time, so they are not different except for standard production differences. The specific MPI call is MPI_Reduce() and it's called three times. I'm assuming the errors are caused by rounding or truncating during the message pass over the network, but my question is how do I prevent this from happening?
Thanks!
What I'm expecting:

I'm expecting accuracy up to 6-8 decimal places when using MPI to message pass over the network between nodes.

What I tried:

Using 1 node, which gave correct accuracy.

Casting everything to long doubles and using MPI_LONG_DOUBLE.



Probably you have distributed the work incorrectly or have a bug in code run by the non-root processor. Without seeing the code ... it's impossible to tell!

Welcome to STack OVerflow. To easy your way in, I recommend giving  Writing the Perfect Question a read-through and taking advantage of the linked checklist.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
